# ASP.NET Core: Huge delay before HTTP request is handled

Tags: .net-core, process, ubuntu-18.04, asp.net-core-3.1, ubuntu-server

I have an ASP.NET Core application running on Ubuntu-server 18.04 on an Intel NUC.

The application receives commands and start up to 4 MPV video player processes on background threads.

When a controller is called, it basically writes a command in one of 4 command queues and returns. Then the command is consumed by a background thread which start/kill the process using `System.Diagnostics.Process`. So the controller operation should be really fast.

At the beginning of the middlewares chain I have a diagnostic middleware that measures the operation duration. This one always reports values near 3-4ms, which is what I expect as I only write in a queue

The problem is that, sometimes, the caller of the API reports times that can span up to several seconds.

I have a network capture showing that there is a huge delay between when the HTTP request is received by the OS and when it is handled by the application.

Logs of the POST requests made by the caller

```
1  Fr Aug  7 10:37:14 CEST 2020;rtsp://192.168.8.12/VideoInput/1/H264/1;53;76
2  Fr Aug  7 10:37:17 CEST 2020;rtsp://192.168.8.9/VideoInput/1/H264/1;54;101
3  Fr Aug  7 10:37:20 CEST 2020;rtsp://192.168.8.12/VideoInput/1/H264/1;55;74
4  Fr Aug  7 10:37:23 CEST 2020;rtsp://192.168.8.9/VideoInput/1/H264/1;56;47
5  Fr Aug  7 10:37:26 CEST 2020;rtsp://192.168.8.12/VideoInput/1/H264/1;57;84
6  Fr Aug  7 10:37:29 CEST 2020;rtsp://192.168.8.9/VideoInput/1/H264/1;58;67
7  Fr Aug  7 10:37:32 CEST 2020;rtsp://192.168.8.12/VideoInput/1/H264/1;59;91
8  Fr Aug  7 10:37:35 CEST 2020;rtsp://192.168.8.9/VideoInput/1/H264/1;60;57
9  Fr Aug  7 10:37:39 CEST 2020;rtsp://192.168.8.12/VideoInput/1/H264/1;61;50
10 Fr Aug  7 10:37:42 CEST 2020;rtsp://192.168.8.9/VideoInput/1/H264/1;62;71
11 Fr Aug  7 10:37:45 CEST 2020;rtsp://192.168.8.12/VideoInput/1/H264/1;63;69
12 Fr Aug  7 10:37:49 CEST 2020;rtsp://192.168.8.9/VideoInput/1/H264/1;64;948
13 Fr Aug  7 10:37:52 CEST 2020;rtsp://192.168.8.12/VideoInput/1/H264/1;65;66
14 Fr Aug  7 10:37:55 CEST 2020;rtsp://192.168.8.9/VideoInput/1/H264/1;66;56
```

The last number is the request time. We can see that most of the case it is < 100ms but here we have a value near 1000ms at line 12

TCP dump, where the slow request have been highlighted

[image: TCP trace]

We can see that the numbers are consistent with the caller.

Now, the logs from ASP.NET Core, where we can see that the request is logged approx 900ms later

```
[10:37:45.198 INF] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics - Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://192.168.8.200:9000/api/v1/video/affect?playerIndex=4 application/json 120
[10:37:45.198 INF] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware - Executing endpoint 'VideoPlayer.Controllers.PlayerController.AffectCamera (VideoPlayer)'
[10:37:45.199 INF] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker - Route matched with {action = "AffectCamera", controller = "Player"}. Executing controller action with signature System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Boolean] AffectCamera(VideoPlayer.Controllers.AffectCameraInputDTO, Int32) on controller VideoPlayer.Controllers.PlayerController (VideoPlayer).
[10:37:45.201 INF] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor - Executing ObjectResult, writing value of type 'System.Boolean'.
[10:37:45.201 INF] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker - Executed action VideoPlayer.Controllers.PlayerController.AffectCamera (VideoPlayer) in 2.0618ms
[10:37:45.202 INF] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware - Executed endpoint 'VideoPlayer.Controllers.PlayerController.AffectCamera (VideoPlayer)'
[10:37:45.202 INF] VideoPlayer.Utils.RequestDiagnosticMiddleware - Request POST /api/v1/video/affect => 200 took 3ms -- IP source: 192.168.8.204
[10:37:45.202 INF] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics - Request finished in 4.2783ms 200 application/json; charset=utf-8

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[10:37:49.110 INF] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics - Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://192.168.8.200:9000/api/v1/video/affect?playerIndex=1 application/json 118
[10:37:49.111 INF] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware - Executing endpoint 'VideoPlayer.Controllers.PlayerController.AffectCamera (VideoPlayer)'
[10:37:49.112 INF] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker - Route matched with {action = "AffectCamera", controller = "Player"}. Executing controller action with signature System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Boolean] AffectCamera(VideoPlayer.Controllers.AffectCameraInputDTO, Int32) on controller VideoPlayer.Controllers.PlayerController (VideoPlayer).
[10:37:49.115 INF] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor - Executing ObjectResult, writing value of type 'System.Boolean'.
[10:37:49.115 INF] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker - Executed action VideoPlayer.Controllers.PlayerController.AffectCamera (VideoPlayer) in 2.4829ms
[10:37:49.116 INF] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware - Executed endpoint 'VideoPlayer.Controllers.PlayerController.AffectCamera (VideoPlayer)'
[10:37:49.116 INF] VideoPlayer.Utils.RequestDiagnosticMiddleware - Request POST /api/v1/video/affect => 200 took 4ms -- IP source: 192.168.8.204
[10:37:49.117 INF] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics - Request finished in 6.534ms 200 application/json; charset=utf-8
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

[10:37:49.127 INF] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics - Request starting HTTP/1.1 POST http://192.168.8.200:9000/api/v1/video/affect?playerIndex=2 application/json 118
[10:37:49.128 INF] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware - Executing endpoint 'VideoPlayer.Controllers.PlayerController.AffectCamera (VideoPlayer)'
[10:37:49.129 INF] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker - Route matched with {action = "AffectCamera", controller = "Player"}. Executing controller action with signature System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Boolean] AffectCamera(VideoPlayer.Controllers.AffectCameraInputDTO, Int32) on controller VideoPlayer.Controllers.PlayerController (VideoPlayer).
[10:37:49.132 INF] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ObjectResultExecutor - Executing ObjectResult, writing value of type 'System.Boolean'.
[10:37:49.132 INF] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker - Executed action VideoPlayer.Controllers.PlayerController.AffectCamera (VideoPlayer) in 2.6272ms
[10:37:49.133 INF] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware - Executed endpoint 'VideoPlayer.Controllers.PlayerController.AffectCamera (VideoPlayer)'
[10:37:49.133 INF] VideoPlayer.Utils.RequestDiagnosticMiddleware - Request POST /api/v1/video/affect => 200 took 5ms -- IP source: 192.168.8.204
[10:37:49.133 INF] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics - Request finished in 6.9064ms 200 application/json; charset=utf-8
```

Any idea what can cause this delay, how I can improve it or analyze it further?

---

EDIT

It seems it is somehow related with the fact I read the MPV process standard and error outputs (to get logs from the player)

I tried to redirect the output and not consume it and everything works fine. As soon as I try to consume the output the issue appears randomly. Even if I don't do any processing with this output.

I tried to read it using different methods

- With the `xxxDataReceived` events
- On a background thread using `StandardOutput` / `StandardError` properties

  - With `ReadLine()`
  - With `Read()` and a buffer

In all the cases lags appear.

If I redirect the output, but don't consume it or if I don't redirect the output, everything is fine.

The process doesn't output a lot. Less than 1 line/second

Comment: Perhaps your cpu is simply busy processing video?

Comment: @freakish The processor is an intel  *i5-8259U* so there are 8 logical cores and htop reports that each MPV process take approx 25% of one core each. So theoretically ony 1 of 7 cores are used.